# How to add different icons for different links in xml loop for blogger template navbar?

Tags: xml, loops, templates, font-awesome, blogger

I am creating a social icon bar for blogger template using font awesome and bootstrap.how can I add different icons for a different link in the following XML loop?

```
 <b:loop values='data:links' var='link'>                    
<li><a expr:href='data:link.target'><i class=' fa fa-facebook fa-lg'/><data:link.name/></a></li>
```

This loop adds the link but with the same icon for all social media links.

Comment: where does the data come from and how do you put it in the loop?

Answer (score -1):

```
<b:loop values='data:links' var='link'>                    
  <li>
    <a expr:href='data:link.target'>
      <i expr:class='"fa fa-lg fa-" + data:link.name'/>
    </a>
  </li> 
</b:loop>
```